# airflow : executor could not be loaded on apache airflow localhost

Tags: airflow, celery, executor

i have install apache airflow on localhost using ubuntu. the executor can't be loaded, this is the traceback :

```
[2022-12-20 22:11:13,927] {manager.py:343} WARNING - Ending without manager process.
[2022-12-20 22:11:13,928] {scheduler_job.py:788} INFO - Exited execute loop
    
    Traceback (most recent call last):
      File "/usr/local/bin/airflow", line 8, in <module>
        sys.exit(main())
      File "/usr/local/lib/python3.8/dist-packages/airflow/__main__.py", line 39, in main
        args.func(args)
      File "/usr/local/lib/python3.8/dist-packages/airflow/cli/cli_parser.py", line 52, in command
        return func(*args, **kwargs)
      File "/usr/local/lib/python3.8/dist-packages/airflow/utils/cli.py", line 108, in wrapper
        return f(*args, **kwargs)
      File "/usr/local/lib/python3.8/dist-packages/airflow/cli/commands/scheduler_command.py", line 73, in scheduler
        _run_scheduler_job(args=args)
      File "/usr/local/lib/python3.8/dist-packages/airflow/cli/commands/scheduler_command.py", line 43, in _run_scheduler_job
        job.run()
      File "/usr/local/lib/python3.8/dist-packages/airflow/jobs/base_job.py", line 247, in run
        self._execute()
      File "/usr/local/lib/python3.8/dist-packages/airflow/jobs/scheduler_job.py", line 738, in _execute
        self.executor.job_id = self.id
      File "/usr/lib/python3.8/functools.py", line 967, in __get__
        val = self.func(instance)
      File "/usr/local/lib/python3.8/dist-packages/airflow/jobs/base_job.py", line 119, in executor
        return ExecutorLoader.get_default_executor()
      File "/usr/local/lib/python3.8/dist-packages/airflow/executors/executor_loader.py", line 77, in get_default_executor
        cls._default_executor = cls.load_executor(executor_name)
      File "/usr/local/lib/python3.8/dist-packages/airflow/executors/executor_loader.py", line 103, in load_executor
        raise AirflowConfigException(
    airflow.exceptions.AirflowConfigException: The module/attribute could not be loaded. Please check "executor" key in "core" section. Current value: "CeleryExecutor".
```

this is config file in airflow.cfg

```
# The executor class that airflow should use. Choices include
# ``SequentialExecutor``, ``LocalExecutor``, ``CeleryExecutor``, ``DaskExecutor``,
# ``KubernetesExecutor``, ``CeleryKubernetesExecutor`` or the
# full import path to the class when using a custom executor.
executor = CeleryExecutor
```